# What's up with non-superpowered leaders of a superpowered team?

Tags: dc, the-legend-of-korra, robin, teen-titans, harley-quinn

Note: I'm using examples from ATLA/TLOK and DC Comics.

---

1. Harley Quinn in the [Harley Quinn series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harley_Quinn_(TV_series)) is a non-superpowered leader of a superpowered team.
2. In ATLA/TLOK, Zaheer pre-airbending was apparently the (non-superpowered) leader of the Red Lotus (consisting of a waterbender, an earthbender and a firebender and possibly others? Not sure).

It's been pointed out to me this isn't new in DC:

3. Robin in several versions of Teen Titans (eg [Cartoon Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teen_Titans_(TV_series))) is a non-superpowered leader of a superpowered team.

Sure there are lots of non-superpowered people who are part of groups, but they're not necessarily leaders of the groups. Examples:

1. Joker in [Legion of Doom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legion_of_Doom) (eg [Harley Quinn series](https://harleyquinn.fandom.com/wiki/Legion_of_Doom))
2. Batman in several versions of Justice League (eg [Cartoon Network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Justice_League_(TV_series)))
3. Sokka, Mai and Ty Lee in ATLA/TLOK

Soooo what's up with them?

I'd ask individually 1 post per each of those 3 but I'm guessing there's possibly a way to unify under whatever trope this is and what's the justification for this weird trope:

What do you call this trope, and why indeed would superpowered people take orders from non-superpowered people?

Comment: Why do trained soldiers with guns take orders from civilian leaders?

Comment: @Adamant civilian leaders? what? ah you mean like elected presidents who were not previously in the military?

Comment: Yes, for instance...any country that is not a military dictatorship.

Comment: @Adamant ah thanks. ok but  errr george bush did serve? ok but well in general. hmmmm....

Comment: @Adamant well...the president still has generals for advisors. the generals were previously soldiers. it's not directly president to soldiers. right?

Comment: Generals are *currently* soldiers (or marines or whatever), just high-ranking ones. [In most countries that are not military dictatorships, the civilian president or other head of state is the Commander-in-Chief](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commander-in-chief#Heads_of_state_as_commanders-in-chief), and their orders are passed down the chain of command to the common soldiers. In a pinch, a president could give orders to a private, and the private would almost certainly listen.

Comment: @Adamant 1 - can i chicken out of your good argument by saying that we're dealing with actual superpowered soldiers meanwhile the leader is not really much different from a president? 2 - ah wait i got it. the leader of the team fights along side the team. like sokka, mai, ty lee. see they're not leaders. harley quinn, robin and i guess zaheer fight alongside their team...usually afaik...i mean...how come superman is batman is the leader of the justice league?

Comment: I think the general idea is that qualities most needed in a leader aren't super-strength, or flight, or laser eyes or whatnot, but rather normal human traits such as intellect, experience, level-headedness, and the ability to plan, organise, and communicate effectively. If a team of superheroes accepts a non-powered individual as their leader, it probably means that individual possesses the aforementioned qualities moreso than anyone else on the team.

Comment: Or, maybe there are supers whose power isn't flashy, like catching on fire and flying, or sticking to walls, but they have super-powered organizational and leadership skills.

Comment: What’s up with sports teams being coached by old people who can’t throw a ball very far any more?

Comment: @LogicDictates ' If a team of superheroes accepts a non-powered individual as their leader, it probably means that individual possesses the aforementioned qualities moreso than anyone else on the team.' --> Why? Sounds a little like toxic positivity in saying mental illnesses like say ADHD are either not or not purely mental illnesses. Like people with ADHD are so creative or something. (Note: here the 'disability' is not having a superpower.)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite The very big keyword there is ANYMORE. The coach is like a general. The non-superpowered person is not a retired person or an ex-superpowered person like say...Yakone. Robin, Harley and presumably Zaheer pre-airbending are fighting on the front lines against people who have superpowers. I could accept it if they weren't leaders like say Sokka, Mai, Ty Lee, Batman or Joker.

Comment: @DavidW I will absolutely accept super organisation as a superpower however lame it may seem to anyone else. for people with ADHD like myself, that is an extremely legit superpower. if zaheer, robin and harley quinn have that kind of superpower then they are not non-superpowered. they are underappreciated like the 'sidekicks' in sky high.

Comment: Related: https://www.pinterest.com/pin/614530311631204342/ What were Robin's powers, short and mad? The answer is: Yes, and mad defeats strong 9 times out of 10. Also, it is implied Robin is the one bankrolling the whole operation. As for the others... A person that is driven to do something often gets into leadership position over a person who is "stronger" but is much less driven. Who is the leader of Justice League, Batman or Superman?

Comment: The overwhelming majority of the people in most worlds with magic don't have any powers, so naturally the majority of people with talents for leadership don't have any powers. This literally has nothing to do with ADHD or "toxic positivity." Paul is not arguing that lacking superpowers makes one a better leader, but that not having them does not make one a *worse* leader.

Comment: To be honest, the question seems to be not so subtly pushing a sort of "might makes right" philosophy. These people are the ones who can beat each other up, so they shouldn't listen to ordinary folks and should just call the shots!

Comment: @BCLC: sure, although in many sports there are great coaches/managers who were never notable players. Soccer’s the only sport I’m familiar with, so Arsene Wenger, Jose Mourinho, and Jürgen Klopp were Robin-level players who went on to lead Superman-level players to defeat Thanos-level opposition and claim Infinity Gauntlet-level trophies (or something).

Comment: @PaulD.Waite they really didn't have superpowers? they were just like robin really?

Comment: @BCLC in terms of kicking footballs, yup. Way better than your average human (like Robin), but nowhere near your Cristian Ronaldo, Lionel Messi, Mo Salah level.

Comment: @LogicDictates another thing: why can't they just get some superpowered person with such leadership qualities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite simply, from an in-universe perspective, **the qualities that make for a good leader do not have any particular reason to be correlated with the presence of unusual abilities.** Further, if most of the population lacks those abilities, most good leaders will not have powers, so it is fairly natural that the leader of a team will not. This ties into my comments about how real-life leaders of highly combat-capable people rarely gain their position by being able to defeat any (or all) of them in single combat, which reaches its pinnacle in the notion of [civilian heads of state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commander-in-chief#Heads_of_state_as_commanders-in-chief) as Commanders-in-Chief of entire armies. If someone with special abilities is competent, they know their strengths and their weaknesses, and if leadership is not one of those strengths, they are willing to step back and let others take the leadership role. In the cases that you mentioned, for instance, someone like Starfire might be much better at fighting than Robin, but she is also much less experienced.

In real life, it is very, very common for fields to recognize that the qualities needed for leadership in a field are quite distinct from those needed to excel in the field itself:

- As previously mentioned, most supreme military commanders are not soldiers, and frequently have never been soldiers. The belief is that their ability to convey the desires of the nation, set high-level strategic goals, and bring people together around a common cause is much more important.
- A very large number of CEOs, college presidents, and so forth do not have much background in the organizations they head. The belief is that their business and organizational acumen is more important than their domain-specific knowledge.

In fact, we could go even further. In many settings with supernatural powers, there might be only, say, 10,000 people in the world with these abilities. That's enough for 100 groups of 100 to each have a leader who is in the top 1% for strategy, tactics, and group cohesion. Not bad, but if the groups recruited their leaders from the population as a whole, they could all have leaders in the top 0.000001% or better. If you were in a group of world-class fighters, wouldn't you want to be led by a world-class tactician and strategist rather than the tactical equivalent of the smartest person in the bar? Having powers might grant a bit of an advantage in terms of first-hand experience, but not enough to offset that kind of gap. And that's if it helps at all: in settings with a diverse array of powers, having one power barely will help to understand the combat applications of the rest.

From an out-of-universe perspective, there is something to be said about the notion that non-powered characters often serve as audience surrogates, under the presumption that it is difficult for normal humans to relate to people who can lift a car. As such, if there are a disproportionate number of mundane leaders of magical teams, this may well be part of the reason.

Comment: Thanks Adamant. Before I dissect/digest thing answer...do you think your answer is specific to DC? Like idk I might move the zaheer thing to another question? I notice in ATLA/TLOK...I don't think non-benders are usually leaders of benders? At least not in the same way as in DC (/Marvel). Or do you think your answer in fact applies to both? Maybe even scifi fantasy in general?